# conflict dependencies manjaro-hello and manjaro-hello-dev are in conflict

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, manjaro

recently I installed Manjaro Xfce but I'm having a problem with some dependencies.I cannot perform update for my OS and is giving an error:
conflict dependencies manjaro-hello and manjaro-hello-dev are in conflict

Answer (score 1):

There is information about this on Manjaro forum, and solutions
[archived.forum.manjaro.org - manjaro-hello-dev and manjaro-hello are in conflict](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/updates-failed-manjaro-hello-dev-and-manjaro-hello-are-in-conflict/60744/15)]

appears to be a non-critical problem caused by installing from an older Manjaro ISO

appears to be possible to choose either and unlikely to cause a problem
manjaro-hello is just the opening welcome screen
can remove it completely, but may be useful if this is first time installing Manjaro